# Vue js table using slice

Tags: vue.js

My date format : 2018-12-29 00:00:00. Can i use .slice(0,10) for my table date field?

```
<template>
    <table striped hover :items="Food" :fields="food_fields">
    </table>
</template>

data() {
        return {
            Food: [......//data],
            food_fields: [
                {
                    key: 'name', label: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    key: 'date', label: 'Date'
                }
            ],
        }
    },
```

Now my table show:

Food Date

Apple 2018-12-29 00:00:00(i want 2018-12-29)

Orange 2018-12-30 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Use simple js date functions or any moment js functions to do convertions.

```
(new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use moment.js instead.

### We have the same problem and im using moment.js for it.

Check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment).